# how to hit enter without creating an enter space (paragraph space)?

Tags: reactjs

When you hit enter a new filed will be created but the problem is the `focus` and the focus will move to the newly created filed, but the problem is : its leave `an enter space in the previous` field
`

[image]

```
import React, { useState } from "react";
import "./styles.css";

export default function App() {
  let elements = [
    { id: 0, text: "first", autoFocus: true },
    { id: 1, text: "second", autoFocus: true },
    { id: 2, text: "third", autoFocus: true }
  ];
  const [state, setstate] = useState(elements);
  function handChange(e) {
    if (e.keyCode == 13) {
      const index = state.findIndex((item) => item.id == e.target.id);
      //i'm using autoFocus to move the focus  (I-beam pointer) to the nex field.
      //but i still get errors with it
      Object.assign(state, (state[index].autoFocus = false));

      setstate((pre) => {
        return [
          ...pre.slice(0, index + 1),
          { id: 3, text: "xxx", autoFocus: true },
          ...pre.slice(index + 1, state.length)
        ];
      });
      setTimeout(() => {
        document.getElementById(index + 1).focus();
      }, 0);
    }
  }

  return (
    <div className="App">
      {state.map((e) => (
        <div contentEditable="true" id={e.id} onKeyUp={handChange}>
          {e.text}
        </div>
      ))}
    </div>
  );
}
```

on [codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/beautiful-silence-c1t1k?file=/src/App.js:0-1092)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

here is a quick hack for it, remove any Enter char from the text

```
 if (e.keyCode == 13) {
      const index = state.findIndex((item) => item.id == e.target.id);
    e.target.innerText = e.target.innerText.split('\n').join('')
// the rest of your code here
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Add `preventDefault` will prevent the default event occurring, in this case, the default event of the `enter` key, which is creating a new line, will be stopped.

```
if (e.keyCode == 13) {
  e.preventDefault(); //This should be at the top of the process.

  //....
}
```